# gnuplot gives error about size but the constraints are included

Tags: windows, powershell, gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot to create a graph calling it from powershell.
I do the following as the beginning of the script

```
reset
set term windows color enhanced size 22cm, 12cm font 10
```

But each time i get error when trying load the file

```
gnuplot> load 'draw.sh'

gnuplot> set terminal windows color enhanced size 22cm, 12cm font 10
                                                      ^
         "draw.sh" line 2: size requires 'width,heigth'
```

Why is there an error and how to fix it?

The original script included:

```
reset
set term postscript enhanced color size 22cm, 12cm font 10
```

And this did not give the error. I need the terminal for windows, the original script was run on Mac. I don't know why this isn't working.

Comment: Whats with the random comma after size 22cm?Why do you have cm (does this app know your monitor resolution and screen size (I don't know the gnuplot synxtax))? Is there meant to be a space? This seems specific to gnuplot... Can you run the command manually and confirm it works?

Comment: Yes, this syntax has to include the comma. In the error is says `... requires 'width,height'`. The command works but I had to edit the original line. I will edit the post to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `help term windows`

> ... size defines the width and height of the window's drawing area in
>   pixels, ...

Thus, because monitor units are in pixel, remove the unit cm.

```
set terminal windows color enhanced size 640, 320 font 10
```